# How to add element in javascript with value option selected

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add element `<p>` with value option selected.

```html
<select id='select'>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
```

if I select 4, element `<p>` will appear 4 `<p>` element.

how to make it using nativ javascript? not jquery

Comment: What does your javascript look like? What have you tried?

Comment: not sure what do you want?

Comment: How to make it using javascript nativ not jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for plain JS implementation, here is what you could do.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let selectEle = document.querySelector("#select");

  function setVal() {
    let val = selectEle.options[selectEle.selectedIndex].value;
    document.querySelector("p").innerText = val;
  }

  selectEle.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    setVal();
  });
  setVal();
});
```

```html
<select id='select'>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<p>text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

With pure javascript you can do it like this create an external function and call it on change.

```
 <script>

        var create_p= function()
        {
            var number =document.getElementById('select').value;
            document.getElementById("add").innerHTML='<p>'+number+'</p>';
        }

        </script>
    <select id='select' onchange="create_p()">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
        <div id="add">

        </div>
```

Comment: thats not working.. here your code https://jsfiddle.net/zn72g5td/ but thanks for your time.. :)

Comment: just tested that and it worked in html tags

Comment: yes.. thats working.. thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

First I advise you give a class or id to the `<p>` you want to put the text in. But the following should get you started.

```
$('#select').on('change', function() {
    $('p').text($('#select').val());
});
```

Comment: This is Jquery Yet  silvia asked for native javascript

Comment: Yes this is jQuery. And if you check his original post he did not specify he did not want jQuery. So a bit harsh to mark this down, and it is still a valid example for those with a similar query that do want to use jQuery.